# How can I select text in a straight vertical column, as opposed to horizontal?

Tags: text-editors

I'm trying to diff two text file logs and I'd like to remove the date/time from both files. This always appears in the same place on the left hand side of each line, as below:

[image]

***I was wondering is there a way to click and drag select all the dates from top to bottom so I can delete them?***

Comment: What editor are you talking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on which text editor you are using, holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> while attempting to make the selection will allow you to select vertically.

Unfortunately, support for this is rather inconsistent, but a couple of examples of places it works (at least on Windows, where I can test it) are Notepad++ and Microsoft Word. Notepad (the default text editor in Windows) does not support this functionality unfortunately (which I believe you are using, based on the screenshot).